# Make input type range thumb appear visible on hover

Tags: css

Quick question - how do I make the slider thumb for input type "range" appear on hover of the slider bar?
This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work

The ID of the slider bar is 'progressbar'.

```
input[type="range"]{

    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-apperance: none;
    border-radius: 26px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 170px;
    background-color: rgb(74,123,197);
}

    input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
visibility: visible;
}

#progressbar:hover input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
visibility: visible;
}
```

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<div id="progressbar">
    <input type="range" min="10" max="100">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 26px;
    height: 3px;
    width: 170px;
    background-color: rgb(74, 123, 197);
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
#progressbar:hover input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3hG9/3/